# How to select a book genre which are borrowed the most

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I have a table called books, and I have to select a book_genre which is borrowed the most(times_borrowed):

```
SELECT book_genre FROM books WHERE times_borrowed = (SELECT MAX(times_borrowed) FROM books);
```

Now I'm selecting only the most borrowed genre, but there are lots of books with the same genres, how would I sum "times_borrowed" for each genre then identify the most borrowed genre?  Thanks for any help or advice.

Comment: Add the DDL, sample data and expected result

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT b.book_genre, SUM(b.times_borrowed) AS TotalBorrowed   -- Get the sum of borrowings
FROM books AS b
GROUP BY book_genre      -- by book_genre
ORDER BY SUM(b.times_borrowed) DESC    -- sort by total desc, so highest first
LIMIT 1;   -- take first result
```

Comment: What if two genres are equally popular?

Comment: In SQL Server you can do `TOP (1) WITH TIES` not sure about MySQL I think you need `row_number()`